# Remove from array by matching start with or regex using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i'm trying to remove value from existing array. i have no idea to how to check the array for specific value and remove it.
my array looks like

```
["Criteria.Make=scion", "Criteria.ModelName=xb", "Criteria.PriceMax=4000", "Criteria.ZipCode=23212", "Criteria.MaxDistance=50"]
```

i want to check if array exist Criteria.PriceMax={what ever dynamically generated value}
i need to remove from the array.

i know i can use grep to remove it but i can come up with the exact need with my code

I check that value like this

```
$.inArray("Criteria.PriceMax",searchUrlBuilder)) > -1
```

won't work properly regex match will be the best but i have no idea how to do that.

thanks

Comment: Can you change your array to an object? Something like `{ Criteria: [ Model: 'xb', PriceMax: 4000 ]}`. This way you wont need *any* regex hacking to find the property you need.

Comment: Rory that won't be possible on my scenario .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be to use `Array.prototype.filter()`:

```
var filteredArray = ["Criteria.Make=scion", "Criteria.ModelName=xb", "Criteria.PriceMax=4000", "Criteria.ZipCode=23212", "Criteria.MaxDistance=50"].filter(function(a){
    return a.indexOf('Criteria.PriceMax') < 0;
});

// returns: ["Criteria.Make=scion", "Criteria.ModelName=xb", "Criteria.ZipCode=23212", "Criteria.MaxDistance=50"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6vG4f/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: I think we posted our answers at *exactly* the same second!

Comment: Array.filter is just *that good*! :) I think that's the first time that's happened to me so far, down to the actual second...

Comment: Me too. :) First time posting at the exact second! In any case, yours is imo better since this trivial requirement does not really need a regex engine match.

Comment: i think this is more acceptable rather go for regex check. thanks David

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.filter():

```
var arr = ["Criteria.Make=scion", "Criteria.ModelName=xb", "Criteria.PriceMax=4000", "Criteria.ZipCode=23212", "Criteria.MaxDistance=50"];

arr = arr.filter(function(_item) {
    return !_item.match(/^Criteria\.PriceMax/);
});
```

returns

```
["Criteria.Make=scion", "Criteria.ModelName=xb", "Criteria.ZipCode=23212", "Criteria.MaxDistance=50"]
```